# How would one add a string value to a newly created xml file in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, string

In my code I'm creating a new xml file with linq to xml and I have a specific format of xml that I'm trying to put into the xml file on creation. However, when I put the string variable in it gives the error "non white space characters cannot be added to content." How would I correctly add that string value to the xml file?

```
string firstPart = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?> 
                     < wiidisc version = ""1"" >
                     < id game = ""RMCE"" disc = ""0"" version = ""0"" >
                     </ id > ";

XDocument doc = new XDocument(firstPart);
doc.Save(riivolutionXmls + @"\" + xmlFileName + ".xml");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't valid XML, you're missing a closing tag for wiidisc.

Also I don't think you can use the constructor to create an XDocument from a string, I think you have to use the XDocument.Parse method:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xdocument.parse?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Linq_XDocument_Parse_System_String_

Comment: Well it's not normal xml, but it's correct for what I'm using it for. And also, thank you it works now.

Comment: Hmm  @BillyNoodles, I had a look and found this: http://rvlution.net/riivolution/images/a/ac/SSBBtemplate.xml

Notice that it does have the wiidisc closing tag.

Comment: @BillyNoodles Don't forget to smash that like button! :D